# jquery .remove doesn't remove some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where users can add products to their order.
I'm using ajax to add the product to the DB and than using .append to show the item on a table at the same screen.

For each product, I have a remove button and when clicked it removes the items from the screen.
My table with the products looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr id="linha_1" data-id="1">
   <td>product 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="linha_2" data-id="2">
   <td>product 1</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And Im using the following code to remove it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btRemover', function(){
  let idremover = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $("#linha_"+idremover).remove();
)}
```

It works fine with the items that the user is adding and removing. BUT when the user select their order to add more items, the page loads the table with the items that were added before, and ONLY for these items, the function doesnt work....it doesnt show any error in the console but the item stays on screen...it looks like that jquery is not findind the item...

I also tried to run a .lenght and it couldn't find the item, even with this item showing up on screen.

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `My table with the products looks like this` what does the table look like when *"the page loads the table with the items that were added before"* - by the way, of course there's no error, either the handler isn't called at all (because the button doesn't have `.btRemover` class, or `$("#linha_"+idremover)` fails to select any element, therefore, jquery just won't even try to `remove` ... I would suggest adding some debugging to the code you posted ... `console.log(idremover, $("#linha_"+idremover).length)` for a start - just before the `.....remove()` line and watch the console

Comment: Is it possible to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? It might be revealing to reproduce the state after the previous items are added and can't be removed.